# Can your run XCode on iPad Pro

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have an iPhone app that does not support iPad devices.  But I would like to give product demos using the simulator on an iPad Pro.  Is / will this be possible?

Comment: Flagging for closure since this isn't a programming question but this has been asked and answered over at the [Ask Different SE site](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65997/xcode-for-ipad/66002).

Comment: Sorry... didn't know Stackoverflow was just coding questions!!

Comment: FYI - all iPhone apps run on all iPads.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is an OS X Application.  It does not run on an iPad Pro.

However, you can install and run your iPhone App on your iPad Pro.